# Does project built on maven creates runtime conflicts between tomcat versions?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I just want to know that if I develop a spring mvc project using maven as built tool, and when I deploy that application after creating war file, will it create conflicts due to tomcat?

To be more specific let me ask you giving an example:
During development I suppose I have tomcat version 6.0.xx and on production server I suppose I have tomcat version is 6.x.x. 
Will this create conflicts?

Hope you got my question..

Comment: About what kind of conflicts you are talking about ? Can you be more specific...

Comment: I am talking about version conflicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It potentially can.

Typically, if you depend on a version of Tomcat and its in your runtime environment, you will need to make the scope of the dependency "provided" such as the following which essentially means maven won't package it up with your app:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>runtimepackage</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I recently encountered this problem with different versions jetty.  One package that was scoped as provided was using Jetty 6 while another package deployed to that runtime environment was using Jetty 8.

- Jetty 6 uses servlet-api 2.5 (has no method called getHeaders())
- Jetty 8 uses servlet-api 3.0 (has a method called getHeaders())

My module using Jetty 8 (hence servlet-api 3.0) and was calling getHeaders() from the HttpServletRequest object.  When I ran locally, everything was fine.  But when deployed and getHeaders() was called, NoSuchMethod exception would trigger.  Mind you I then changed my local setup to match that of the environment more closely and was able to reproduce the issue.

Hope that makes sense and helps